# Log Into User Area But Can't Access Rest of Site

Tags: html, .htaccess

I recently created a password-authenticated user area on my website, and I am working on creating individual user subdirectories, which has been successful.

The problem is, once I'm logged in, I can't seem to access the rest of the page using the nav bar.

`/htdocs/students` is a password-authenticated area redirected in `.htaccess` by `username`

`htdocs/students/students` contains the user subdirectories during this transition

`htdocs/students/students/mynamestudents/` is the current landing subdirectory.

In my nav bar, I have a link for `../../../index.html` to get back to the homepage that's not password authenticated, but when I click on the link I get a `404 error` page and the URL reads `students/students/mynamestudents/index.html/student.html`

Is the `.htaccess` still in effect and trying to redirect still?  How do I fix this?

EDIT:
This is my .htaccess file:

```
Options -Indexes

AuthType Basic
AuthName "restricted area"
AuthUserFile /path/to/students/.access.pwd
AuthPam_Enabled off

require valid-user

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/students/students/.+/
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_USER} (.+)
RewriteRule (.*) /students/students/%1/$1/student.html [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

What is you did a root path to your index.html?

/index.html

http://www.motive.co.nz/glossary/linking.php

Are you changing the document root folder in your .htaccess? This could be causing the issue.

Comment: My index.html is in the root folder htdocs, using root-relative linking my href should be correct sans htaccess.  This is what I have for htaccess, mostly copy pasted from one my server host created for me and edited for the redirect by username:

Options -Indexes

AuthType Basic
AuthName "restricted area"
AuthUserFile /data/20/4/137/124/4300124/user/4917526/htdocs/students/.access.pwd
AuthPam_Enabled off

require valid-user

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/students/students/.+/
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_USER} (.+)
RewriteRule (.*) /students/students/%1/$1/student.html [L,R=301]